# What are some archaeological discoveries from Ancient Civilizations that baffled mathematicians?

Tags: mathematics, ancient

The Ancient Civilizations of Earth are highly advanced than accredited for.
Their respect for numerology throughout various parts of Earth is interesting.

It baffles me how they did it with such limited technology. Forcing humanity to rely on their intelligence.

### Question

What are the most peculiar discoveries in Ancient Civilizations that baffle mathematicians?

Comment: The paragraphs leading up to the question are irrelevant to the question. There is no reason that all or even most ancient civilizations have to be more advanced than is known, and it is not clear what “it” they “did” that you are talking about. We know a lot about the ancient Roman civilization and it contributed nothing of value to mathematics.

Comment: [Babylonian clay tablet Plimpton 322](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plimpton_322) from c. 1800 contains a list Pythagorean triples with fairly large integers, which many mathematicians found to be impressive for its time.  But it is also an example of how claims about "highly advanced" ancient civilizations are often overhyped in pop literature, see [Don't Fall for Babylonian Trigonometry Hype by Lamb](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/dont-fall-for-babylonian-trigonometry-hype/).